# Soul Arbiter's Maze Solutions

Tags: darksiders-2

I'm going around trying to mop up all the side quests in Darksiders 2 before I complete the  final levels of the game. I'm currently trying to get through Soul Arbiter's Maze in the Kingdom of the Dead, but I haven't gathered up all of the Soul Arbiter's Scrolls in order to get the directions for each level of the maze. I know I don't need the Scrolls in order to succeed at the solutions, and I know that each level also has a "secret" solution that'll take you to a treasure chest.

So what are the "Secret" Directions and Next Level Directions for each of the 10 levels of the Soul Arbiter's Maze?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Maze Floor 1 Directions To Exit: N, W.
Floor 1 Path To Secret Treasure: S, E.

Maze Floor 2 Directions To Exit: E, S, N.
Floor 2 Path To Secret Treasure: N, N.

Maze Floor 3 Directions To Exit: W, E, N, N.
Floor 3 Path To Secret Treasure: N, S, E.

Maze Floor 4 Directions To Exit: E, W, N, S.
Floor 4 Path To Secret Treasure: W, E, N.

Maze Floor 5 Directions To Exit: W, W, N, E.
Floor 5 Path To Secret Treasure: W, N, S.

Maze Floor 6 Directions To Exit: S, E, E, N, N.
Floor 6 Path To Secret Treasure: E, E, E, S.

Maze Floor 7 Directions To Exit: S, W, E, E, E.
Floor 7 Path To Secret Treasure: S, S, W, N, N.

Maze Floor 8 Directions To Exit: N, W, N, W, E.
Floor 8 Path To Secret Treasure: N, S, S, E, N.

Maze Floor 9 Directions To Exit: E, N, E, N, S.
Floor 9 Path To Secret Treasure: S, W, E, E, N.

Maze Floor 10 Directions To Exit: W, E, N, S, W.
Floor 10 Path To Secret Treasure: N, S, E, W.
```